# Countability of a partially ordered set

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory

First of all, thank you in advance to everyone who will look at my question, I saw a question yesterday and I thought of such a solution to the question, but I was not sure if it was my mistake or not, I would be very grateful if you could help me. Here is the question
$$(A,\leq) \text{ is an poset and for every } x\in A \text { the set }R_x=\{y \in A : y\leq x\} \text { or the set } \\ L_x=\{y \in A : x \leq y\} \text{ is finite set then A is a countable set }$$
I am adding my solution below

Comment: So $L_x$ is the set of elements to the right of $x$, and $R_x$ is the set of elements to the left of $x$?

Comment: Let $A$ be an uncountable set, and define the partial order on $A$ so that $x\le y\iff x=y$. Then $L_x=R_x=\{x\}$ for all $x\in A$.

Comment: On the other hand, suppose $(A,\le)$ is a **totally** ordered set such that, for each $x\in A$, either $L_x$ or $R_x$ is finite. Then $A$ is countable, because it is the union of the two countable sets $\{x\in A:L_x\text{ is finite}\}$ and $\{x\in A:R_x\text{ is finite}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The set $A$ is not finite, so it will not be countable

Let $x_0 \in A$ and let $R_{x_0}=\{y \in A : y \leq x_0 \}$ be finite and $L_{x_0}=\{y \in A : x_0 \leq y \}$  for this element.
Then $R_{x_0}=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n\}$ such that $x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n \in A$ and $x_0 \leq x_i$ for every $i=1,2,\ldots n$. If $ x_i \leq y $ for $y \in A $ then $x_0 \leq y$ will be satisfied if $\{y \in A : x_i \leq y \} \subseteq \{y \in A : x_0 \leq y \}=L_{x_0}$ (for $i=1,2,\ldots , n$)

Hence it follows that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n \{y \in A : x_i \leq y \} = L_{x_0}$.
For every $i=1,2,\ldots n $ $\{y \in A : x_i \leq y \} \subseteq L_{x_0}$, so $\bigcup_{i=1}^n \{y \in A : x_i \leq y \} \subseteq L_{x_0}$.

Let see $ L_{x_0}  \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n \{y \in A : x_i \leq y \}$. Conversely, let us assume the converse, in which case $\exists y_1 \in L_{x_0} $ such that $y_1 \notin \bigcup_{i=1}^n \{y \in A : x_i \leq y \} $.

If $y_1 \in L_{x_0}$ then $x_0\leq y_1$ and $y_1 \notin L_{x_0}$ then $x_0\leq y_1 \bigcup_{i=1}^n \{y \in A : x_i \leq y \}$ $x_i \leq y_1$ for every i. In this case $y_1 \in R_{x_0}$ but in this case a new element appears in our finite set, which is a contradiction. Similarly, the assumption that $L_{x_0}$ is finite will also lead to a contradiction. Then A is finite and therefore countable.

Comment: Your first sentence says "The set $A$ is not finite, so it will not be countable" but your last sentence says "Then $A$ is finite and therefore countable." How do you reconcile this seeming contradiction?